# Publishing a WebApp Bot from VS to azure,Bot not working

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, botframework

I have a web app bot which perfectly works locally, but when I publish it through Visual Studio, the bot functionality doesn't change but stays same as the code present in the starting age. I do get "PUBLISHED SUCCESSFULLY" when i publish. Where can the problem persist ?

Comment: bot doesn't work and there is no error ?

Comment: you can check error by debugging: [debug bot from visual studio](https://hasanmahmood.com/2019/03/05/debugbotservicelocally/)

Comment: @AkberIqbal yes there is no error.

Comment: @KadhaRamKaushik, it sounds like you created a bot on Azure, as well? And, you are trying to publish to that bot? If so, be sure check "Remove additional files at destination". If you don't you can experience a number of issue, including the one you describe. This option is found in Publish => App Service => Advanced... => File Publish Options.

Answer (score 0):

As Steven says, you should check the "Remove additional files at destination" before publish.

[image: Configuration]

Comment: @Steven tried this, but there is no difference in the working. My endpoint is http://luis-csharp-bot-kaushik.azurewebsites.net/ from which i don't get any reply when i tried to access it from the emulator.

Comment: Did you set the **Application Id** and **Application Password** in the **Web.config** in the project and into Emulator **chat configuration**?

Comment: @KadhaRamKaushik, you won't be able to access the production endpoint from Emulator. Emulator is for local development only (ex. "http://localhost:3978/api/messages"). To access external resources (ex. Teams or Facebook) you would use a tunnel to create that pathway from your local bot to your ABS bot (to setup, read: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/). What happens when you use the "Test in Web Chat" feature in your ABS bot?

Comment: @StevenKanberg in the ""Test in web chat" feature my bot doesn't work. it works as the basic bot with out any implementations I did in VS.